# SQL Filter in Azure Service bus, how to filter on multiple conditions?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to write a SQL query-ish filter on Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription, where i want to filter on multiple conditions and if none of them match then the message will be displayed in that topic.

This is what i have tried, both with () and without, also with sys.label on each line enclosed in () with OR between

`sys.label = 'V2' AND (custom_prop1 != 'blabla' OR custom_prop1 != 'blabla2' OR custom_prop1 != 'blabla3' OR custom_prop1 != 'blabla3')`

This works if i only filter with sys.label and 1 custom property, but when trying to filter on multiple it doesnt work?

How do i do it correct?